# Windows has the option to protect an exported private key using a domain account. How does this work?

Tags: certificates, windows, key-management

When exporting a cert+key in Windows, you're given 2 choices to protect it: either a password/passphrase or a domain account.

My question is, how does this account-based protection work? Is it more or less secure than using a good password?

[image]

Comment: Here is description: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13922.certificate-pfx-export-and-import-using-ad-ds-account-protection.aspx